# Ruby apply string interpolation to a single-quote string

Tags: ruby, string, string-interpolation

I have a string that contains some interpolated statements, like `description='Hello! I am #{self.name}'`. This string is stored as-is in the database; so without the automatic string interpolation applied.

I want to apply this interpolation at a later date. I could do something crazy like `eval("\"+description+\"")` but there has to be a nicer, more ruby-esque way to do this, right?

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals#The_.25_Notation

Comment: In case of the eval you should trust the data. In other case it is a huge security risk.

Answer (score 7):

Use the `%` operator:

```
'database store string says: %{param}' % {param: 'noice'}
#=> "database store string says: noice"
```

Comment: Note that the named reference starts with `%`, not `#`

Answer (score 0):

```
class Person
  attr_reader :name

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end

  def description
    'Hello! I am #{self.name}'
  end

  def interpolated_description
    description.split('#').map { |v| v.match(/\{(.*)\}/) ? send($1.split('.').last) : v  }.join
  end
end

p = Person.new('Bot')

p.interpolated_description
=> "Hello! I am Bot"
```

How about this?